# tradingview pinescript cannot use mutable variable in security function as an argument

Tags: pine-script

Before writing this i tried certain idea given here still not working so asking again.

This is the V4 code
V2 =True
SarUp interger vlue emaslow integer value
//code from here

```
get_pltval(V2,sarUp,emaSlow) =>
    pltval = 0.0
    plval := V2 ? sarUp <= ohlc4 and sarUp[2] > high and sarUp[3] > high and sarUp[4] > high ? 1 : 0 : ohlc4 > emaSlow ? 1 : 0

var _src = 0.0 
_src := get_pltval(V2,sarUp,emaSlow)

test = security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, _src, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_off)
```

Error  Cannot use mutable variable as an argument in security function

Any solution this problem .Please share

Answer (score 0):

`barmerge` and `lookahead` are "off" by default, so no need to explicitly define them. You can call a function from `security()`:

```
//@version=4
study("")
get_pltval(V2,sarUp,emaSlow) =>
    pltval = 0.0
    plval := V2 ? sarUp <= ohlc4 and sarUp[2] > high and sarUp[3] > high and sarUp[4] > high ? 1 : 0 : ohlc4 > emaSlow ? 1 : 0

test = security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, get_pltval(V2,sarUp,emaSlow))
```

Comment: Sorry but without a complete, compilable snippet, there's no way I can help you further.